# Can I take a one-month French language course in Paris if I have a Spanish D type student visa?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, france, spain, study

I am an Indian citizen holding an Indian passport with a Spanish multi-entry type D student visa for less than 180 days. I secured this visa for a non-remunerable internship, which I have just completed.

My visa is still valid for a little more than a month and I have come to Paris. I am a chef and I wish to do another stage (non-remunerable internship) here in Paris for a month, for which I have already been accepted. At this stage, I need a document called *Convention de stage* and for this reason I need to join a French language learning course here, which will provide the document. Am I authorized to take this 20-hour per week course and do the internship as well?

From my research and understanding, the type D visa is equivalent to being a resident, in which case I can take the course without having a separate French student visa. Is that correct?

Comment: What does the language school have to say about this, if anything?